# Keycloak behind nginx reverse proxy with SSL

Tags: java, spring, docker, nginx, ssl

I have a problem with setting up an environment (all of them on the same machine) consisting of:

- Nginx - reverse proxy
- Docker:

  - Keycloak - authorization
  - Gateway with microservices (based on java / spring boot)

I think my problem is connected with SSL certificate. My certificate with private key is in nginx/ssl folder and added in configuration. Keycloak is up with options for running behind reverse proxy. When I want to connect with microservices behing gateway I am redirected to keycloak login page. After filling form and submit it I'm getting this message: `connection timed out example.com/ip_address:443` (of course I changed the original domain and ip). Why I'am getting this kind of error? Below I putted configuration files that I am using (domain, ip's and password changed).

### Keycloak - docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: keycloak_db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: keycloak_adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5001:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:12.0.2
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_ADDR=${DB_ADDR}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - REDIRECT_SOCKET=proxy-https
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=${KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL}
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl -f http://localhost:8080/auth || exit 1"
      start_period: 30s
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres-vol:
```

### nginx.conf (only server configuration)

```
    server {
        listen 80; 
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
        
    server  {
        
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

        location /404{          
        }
            
        location /auth {
            proxy_pass http://address_ip:8090;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;                     
        }
        
        location /auth/admin {
            proxy_pass http://address_ip:8090;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;         
        }
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://address_ip:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            add_header        Front-End-Https        on;            
        }
        
        error_page 404 /40x.html;
            location = /40x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        
        error_page 502 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    }
```

### Gateway - application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  use-forward-headers: true

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    org.springframework.web.HttpLogging: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: DEBUG

spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - PATCH
              - DELETE
            allowedHeaders: "*"
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false

#'dev' proflie
---

spring:
  profiles: dev
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - openid
              - email
              - profile
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: https://dev.example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            token-uri: https://dev.example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-info-uri: https://dev.example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            jwk-set-uri: https://dev.example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/certs

#'prod' proflie
---

spring:
  profiles: prod
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - openid
              - email
              - profile
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: https://example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            token-uri: https://example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-info-uri: https://example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            jwk-set-uri: https://example.com/auth/realms/gateway/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

### Gateway dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /opt/workdir

ARG CERT_PATH="./build/certificates/prod.pfx"
ARG CERT_NAME="prod.pfx"

#import cert into java
COPY $CERT_PATH /opt/workdir/

RUN echo yes | keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore prod.pfx -srcstorepass pass -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore prod.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -deststorepass pass
COPY target/gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
RUN jarsigner -keystore prod.p12 -storepass pass /app/app.jar 1
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Any progress on this? I am trying to do something similar, except LXD instead of docker.
I'm getting CORS like issues though; when loading the login screen with HTTPS keycloak wants to load the keycloak.js file with http and it uses the IP instead of the domain.